# Good website for checking train options in Spain/Portugal?

Tags: trains, spain, portugal

renfe.com says they **do not** go from Logroño to Lisbon.  Rome2Rio says they do, if you are willing to change trains **many** times.  And of course, Rome2Rio cannot be trusted for price or schedule.

Is there a website (or smartphone app) more reliable than Rome2Rio to find and/or book such a trip?  I hope we don't have to go forty kilometers to the nearest RenFe office to decide whether to return there for the actual trip.

Comment: CFF.ch? Pretty long overnight trip, but a single change. Don’t know about buying the ticket though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The man in seat 61](https://www.seat61.com/) provides a lot of information on train travel within Europe, written by a hobbyist. His website doesn't support booking (although it recommends sites to book), but it can be useful for information about routes between major cities, and gives additional information on things like views from the window which might influence your choice of route. In this case it would give you options for trains between [Madrid and Lisbon](https://www.seat61.com/international-trains/trains-from-Madrid.htm#Spain-Portugal), and Renfe should be able to tell you about trains from Logroño to Madrid. Alternatively, if you follow the man in seat 61's booking recommendation, https://loco2.com/, it proposes a 12:40 hour Logroño-Lisboa route with one change for 75€.

Another booking site which I haven't used but which I expect to be good is https://www.trainline.eu/. The original UK site (thetrainline.com) is my standard way of checking train routes in the UK. However, in this case the route it finds is slower and more expensive (14:40, 100€).